# Renderer function for ExtJS chart series

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJS series renderer function to set the `fill` property of scatter chart, instead of using `markerConfig` property. Since I want to fill different color for each points. Its working fine.

```
renderer : function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
   Ext.apply(attr, {
       fill : '#F00'
   }
}
```

But I want to set the `type` property, so that each point will show in different types like circle, cross, plus, diamond and so on. It is not working. And radius of the scatter point, I am unable to set the property in renderer function.

How do I do that in the renderer function?

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can just use these types (according to documentation):

- circle - To draw circles. You can set the radius by using the radius
  parameter in the sprite configuration.
- rect - To render rectangles. You can set the width and height of the
  rectangle by using the width and height parameters in the sprite
  configuration.
- text - To render text as a sprite. You can set the font/font-size by
  using the font parameter.
- path - The most powerful sprite type. With it you can create
  arbitrary shapes by using the SVG path syntax. You can find a quick
  tutorial on to how to get started with the path syntax here.

so for example if you need plus you can do:

```
renderer : function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
    var plus="M-1.1538461538461537,-1.1538461538461537l0,-2.3076923076923075,2.3076923076923075,0,0,2.3076923076923075,2.3076923076923075,0,0,2.3076923076923075,-2.3076923076923075,0,0,2.3076923076923075,-2.3076923076923075,0,0,-2.3076923076923075,-2.3076923076923075,0,0,-2.3076923076923075,z";
    return Ext.apply(attr, { fill: '#F00', type: 'path', path: plus });
}
```

Documentation link: http://www.sencha.com/learn/drawing-and-charting/